# whitelist contract's address showing undefined without showing any error message

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/LearnWeb3DAO/Whitelist-Dapp) here to learn developing whitelist contract. My node verion is 18.12.1 and testnet is sepolia. I am currently on windows11 OS.

whitelist.sol:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Whitelist {
    uint8 public maxWhitelistAddress;
    mapping(address=>bool) public whitelistedAddresses;
    uint8 public numAddressesWhitelisted;

    constructor(uint8 _maxWhitelistAddress){
        maxWhitelistAddress=_maxWhitelistAddress;
    }

    function addAddressToWhitelist() public{
        require(!whitelistedAddresses[msg.sender], "Sender has already been whitelisted");
        require(numAddressesWhitelisted>=maxWhitelistAddress, "Max whitelist number has been reached");
        whitelistedAddresses[msg.sender]=true;
        numAddressesWhitelisted+=1;
    }
}
```

.env:

```
#I have used the actual API_KEY_URL and the private key, here only dummy values are provided
ALCHEMY_API_KEY_URL="https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/api-key"
SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY="sepolia-private-key"
```

hardhat.config.js:

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config({path:".env"})
/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
const ALCHEMY_API_KEY_URL=process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY_URL;
const SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY=process.env.SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY;
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.9",
  networks:{
    sepolia:{
      url:ALCHEMY_API_KEY_URL,
      accounts:[SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY]
    },
  },
};
```

My deploy.js file's code:

```
const {ethers} = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const whitelistContract=await ethers.getContractFactory("Whitelist");
  const deployedWhitelistContract=await whitelistContract.deploy(10);

  // Wait for the contract to be deployed before calling the console.log() function.
  await deployedWhitelistContract.waitForDeployment();

  console.log(
    "whitelist contract address: ",
    deployedWhitelistContract.address
  );
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

The only difference here is I am using `waitForDeployment()` instead of `deployed()`, as I have learned after getting `deployed is not a function` error, that `deployed` is now deprecated.

I am supposed to get the whitelist contract's address. But after compiling and running npx `hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network sepolia`, it is printing `whitelist contract address:  undefined` without showing any error.

I have tried as much as possible to follow the tutorial. I am quite new to web3 development. Any constructive criticism is appreciated. Please let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mostly because `address` is now changed to `target`.

use

`deployedWhitelistContract.target`

instead of :

`deployedWhitelistContract.address`

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. Is there any documentation about the things that have changed?

Comment: I am not sure about that, as I got to know from the errors itself. But you can check the release for sure - https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/releases